# Decomposition of a linear map to nilpotent and diagonalizable matrices.

Tags: diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

**Question**

Let $V$ be a vector space over the complex field $C$ , and let $T$ be an linear map $V\rightarrow V$. Show that exists a pair of linear maps $D$ and $N$ such that $D+N=A$, $D$ is diagonalizable, $N$ is nilpotent, and DN=ND.

I found this 
[endomorphism as sum of two endomorphisms (nilpotent and diagonalizable)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145518/endomorphism-as-sum-of-two-endomorphisms-nilpotent-and-diagonalizable)
where he said "you can transform so that ϕ is on jordan form, and then split this matrix in a diagonal and a nilpotent"

But I didn't get his explanation. How can I decompose the jordan marix of T? any why does it proves the commute  and sum of the linear maps?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever heard of Dunford decomposition?

Comment: No, not at all. Not this and not semi-simple transformations.
 
I guess I suppose to solve it using Jordan Form because that's what we focus on right now..