# Every Endomorphism is a Sum of two normal Endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do i show this? I knwo the basic properties of normal Endomorphisms like $$\langle L(v),L(w)\rangle = \langle L^*(v),L^*(w)\rangle $$

$$L^*\circ L = L\circ L^*$$

but i don't really know how to tackle this problem.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145518/endomorphism-as-sum-of-two-endomorphisms-nilpotent-and-diagonalizable but i didn't really help me with my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}(L+L^*)+\frac{1}{2}(L-L^*)
$$