# sum of two invariant subspaces given an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

I've been trying to solve this problem, but to be honest I have no clue on how to tackle it.

> Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$, and a endomorphism $T: V \to V$. Prove that $V$ can be uniquely split as $V_0+V_1$ such that $T(V_0)\subset V_0$, $T(V_1)\subset V_1$ , $T|_{V_0}$ nilpotent and $T|_{V_1}$ invertible.

Found [something similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145518/endomorphism-as-sum-of-two-endomorphisms-nilpotent-and-diagonalizable),but don't know if is the same.

Like the straightforward way is to consider $\beta_i$ a basis for $V_i$, $i=0,1$, and show that $\beta=\beta_0\cup \beta _1$ is a basis for $V$ and somehow use the properties of the restrictions of $T$ to each subspace. Although can't figure how.

Comment: The way I think about it is writing $T$ using a matrix form (for some fixed basis) then obtaining the Jordan canonical form, say $T=PJP^{-1}$ where the zero eigenvalue block of $J$ (if it exists) is pushed to the bottom. Then take $V_0$ to be the subspace of $V$ spanned by that last zero eigenvalue block of $J$, and take $V_1$ to be spanned by the other blocks of $J$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Two important subspaces coming with any endomorphism are its kernel and its image. I would look at these first. Particularly, what happens when they share common non-zero vectors, and when you iterate T on each of them.